# How to modify elements of a list as I iterate through them in Kotlin ("Val cannot be reasigned")?

Tags: list, kotlin, iterator

I am trying to make a kotlin function that given a list of numbers and another separate number, will go over the list substracting one from each element, and then add another element at the end of the list if a condition is met. This is my code:

```
fun listCalculator(myList:MutableList<Int>, number:Int) {

for (i in 0..number){

     val iterator = myList.listIterator()
     for (item in iterator) {

         item -= 1

         if (item == 0) {iterator.add(10)}
         println(myList.toString())

}}}
```

And this is the list I am passing to the function:

```
var testList:MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf(1,7,0,1)
```

The first error I run into is on line 5, when I try to subtract 1 from the value of `item`: `'Val cannot be reassigned'`. The second problem I have is that this code adds the new element `10` right after the element that met the `(item == 0)` condition, but I want it at the end of the list.

Comment: Do you have to modify the existing list or would it be acceptable to create a new list?

Comment: For the purposes of this task it is okay to create a new list. However if it is possible to modify this list I would like to know how it's done since I am trying to learn how lists work in Kotlin rather than just make this bit of code work "by any means".

Comment: Part of the Kotlin learning experience is to avoid modifying collections and instead create new collections :-) This is why I asked. Of course both approaches are possible, it is just preferable and often cleaner to create copies. One additional question: do you need to add single `10` at the end if any item is `0` or add `10` per each `0` item?

Comment: I see! I am new to Kotlin, thank you for explaining. I need to add one extra "10" to the list for each element that is 0. If the list is [1,1] I need it to become [0,0] and then [0,0,10,10].

Comment: Actually, in this specific case it seems much easier to modify the collection in-place. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, when iterating over a collection, we don't receive some kind of a pointer to the current item. `item` in your example is only a copy of the current item and modifying it would not affect the list. This is one reason why `item` is read-only - otherwise it would be misleading as developers would think they modified the list, but in fact they would not. In order to replace the current item we have to either use [ListIterator.set()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#set(E)) or access the item using its index.

Secondly, it would be tricky to add new items at the end while iterating over the same collection. It is much easier to just remember the number of `0` items and add `10` items after we finish iterating.

Solution using `ListIterator.set()`:

```kotlin
fun listCalculator(myList: MutableList<Int>, number: Int) {
    for (i in 0..number) {
        var counter = 0
        val iterator = myList.listIterator()
        for (item in iterator) {
            iterator.set(item - 1)

            if (item == 1) {
                counter++
            }
        }

        repeat(counter) { myList += 10 }
    }
}
```

Solution where we iterate over indices and access the current item manually:

```kotlin
fun listCalculator(myList: MutableList<Int>, number: Int) {
    for (i in 0..number) {
        var counter = 0
        for (index in myList.indices) {
            val item = --myList[index]

            if (item == 0) {
                counter++
            }
        }

        repeat(counter) { myList += 10 }
    }
}
```

Also note that the outer loop does not run `number` times, but `number + 1` times. If you intended to execute it `number` times, then you have to use `for (i in 0 until number) { ... }` or just: `repeat(number) { ... }`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it solves the issue with adding the numbers at the end of the list. However it is leaving out the important part that actually gives me an error, the part where I try to modify the value of each item in the list and receive the "Val cannot be reassigned" error. Can you tell me how to fix that part?

Comment: The first paragraph addresses this problem. We can't modify items like this, because iterators do not provide functionality of replacing the current item. `item` is only a copy of the data in the list, so even if it would be possible to modify `item` variable, it would not modify the list. We have to replace the item using its index.

Comment: I see now, sorry, I had misread. Thank you so much for your answer and patience, I finally understand how Kotlin lists work now :D

Comment: Ohh, actually I'm wrong. `ListIterator` provides `set()`. I'll update my answer, however, most of the answer is still true. `item` is only a copy and modifying it would not modify the list.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer, adding two alternatives. I also explained the problem with `item` being read-only.

Comment: Ahh I see now! I had tried to use set() before asking the question but now I see why I was using it wrong. Thank you!